# Twilio Flow replying to "Send and wait for reply" not triggering next widget

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to set up a Flow with a `Send and wait for reply` widget (triggered with the REST API), however, the reply doesn't seem to trigger the next widget (handle_welcome...) and instead triggers the Incoming Message for the Flow (handle_incoming...).

Is there a way to set up a Flow so that it knows that the received SMS is a reply and not just a generic Incoming Message?

Here is a screenshot of the flow:
[image: Flow]

I only have one number set up and that is set to trigger the Studio Flow on an incoming message.
Also, I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I have **Concurrent calls trigger** enabled.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works tbh. The _Send & Wait For Reply_ widget uses the number it received the message from to create a session. It then associates subsequent received messages to this session and can distinguish if there was a reply. So behind an _Incoming Message_ this works because there's a session but not sure if you can make it work behind a _REST API_ as Twilio effectively doesn't now about the number it receives a message from and hence goes into the _Incoming Message_ trigger.

Comment: @yvesonline Ah, that makes sense. I guess I'd assumed that it would generate a session id for the *Send & Wait For Reply* if there wasn't one already. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it's a tricky one. I mean you're creating an execution via the REST API with _from_ and _to_ number so I'd have thought Twilio Flow can create the session anyway but I guess when it receives it it doesn't know how to route it. Can you rewrite the logic so that you respond to it in `handle_incoming...`?

Comment: @yvesonline Yeah, I could in this case, however, I have another use case where I'd want to essentially chain multiple Send/Reply. No worries, I'll have to see if there's a different approach.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you do not have the phone number associated to Service. I had created a service, associated the number and that seems to have short circuited the flow. I logged a ticket with Twilio and they kindly instructed me to remove it. Once I removed it, the flow worked as expected:

1. Remove the number (:warning: if this is not required for your service. Else, purchase a new number and use that with your flow)
   [image: Twilio Service]
2. Click Remove
   [image: remove phone number from service]

### References

- [Twilio Studio Rest v2](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2)
- [Twilio Execute Flow](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/execution#quick-example)
- [Twilio Send & Respond Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/send-wait-reply)

Answer (score 1):

To use the REST API trigger with a subsequent wait and reply widget, the phone number you send from can not be associated with a messaging service.
Remove that association and then you will be able to use the flow with both REST API trigger and incoming message trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a messaging service when you trigger a Studio API call, but you need to set the `From` to the `MessagingServiceSID`, not the phone number.

```
curl -X POST https://studio.twilio.com/v1/Flows/FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Executions \
  --data-urlencode "To=<ToPhoneNumber>" \
  --data-urlencode "From=<MessagingServiceSID>" \
  -u "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token"
```

Here is the [relevant support article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/17894300978843-FAQ-Why-Does-the-Send-Wait-for-Reply-Widget-Stop-Collecting-the-Users-Response-and-Creates-a-New-Execution-for-US-A2P-Registered-10DLC-Numbers).

Remember to enable Sticky Sender in the messaging service so the messages always come from the same number.